# How can I wait until all variables are loaded before running the graphQL query?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, prisma-graphql

The issue is that my graphQL query's variables are `undefined` for a split second (because they have to load first), leading to a `400 bad request`. Here's the basic JSX:

```
const patternsQuery = gql`
  query PatternQuery($id: String!) {
    pattern(id: $id) {
      id
    }
  }
`
const Component = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(patternsQuery, {
    variables: { id: useRouter().query.id }
  })
  console.log(data)
  return <div>{data?.pattern.name}</div>
}
```

`useRouter().query.id` takes a split second to load. For that reason, the variables are `{ id: undefined }` at first. Here's a screenshot of my browser's console given the code above:
[image]

Comment: use `skip` option, read apollo api docs

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to prevent useQuery for running when state changes - React, Apollo, GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60799495/how-to-prevent-usequery-for-running-when-state-changes-react-apollo-graphql)? Add `skip: !useRouter().query.id` to the `useQuery`'s options object.

Comment: @juliomalves Absolutely! Thanks, I should have read the docs more in depth.